# How to consecutively subset an array and count the number of iterations?

Tags: r, arrays, loops, subset

I need to repeatedly apply a function on the resultant arrays until all data in the array is reduced to a single set, and count the number of iterations.

**Data**
Array ar

```
structure(c(0, 11, 17, 15, 22, 67, 73, 68, 31, 31, 28, 33, 34, 
32, 11, 0, 9, 12, 21, 67, 73, 67, 35, 30, 34, 67, 60, 36, 17, 
9, 0, 6, 19, 70, 74, 68, 36, 36, 36, 64, 66, 39, 15, 12, 6, 0, 
13, 64, 69, 66, 34, 37, 39, 77, 65, 45, 22, 21, 19, 13, 0, 59, 
60, 66, 38, 39, 39, 40, 43, 43, 67, 67, 70, 64, 59, 0, 10, 18, 
77, 75, 78, 93, 93, 85, 73, 73, 74, 69, 60, 10, 0, 15, 76, 74, 
80, 103, 101, 95, 68, 67, 68, 66, 66, 18, 15, 0, 59, 65, 73, 
90, 87, 82, 31, 35, 36, 34, 38, 77, 76, 59, 0, 8, 19, 24, 28, 
32, 31, 30, 36, 37, 39, 75, 74, 65, 8, 0, 12, 20, 22, 23, 28, 
34, 36, 39, 39, 78, 80, 73, 19, 12, 0, 6, 14, 18, 33, 67, 64, 
77, 40, 93, 103, 90, 24, 20, 6, 0, 2, 8, 34, 60, 66, 65, 43, 
93, 101, 87, 28, 22, 14, 2, 0, 6, 32, 36, 39, 45, 43, 85, 95, 
82, 32, 23, 18, 8, 6, 0), .Dim = c(14L, 14L))
```

From

```
a<-colSums(ar<25)
b<-which.max(a)
c<-ar[ar[,b] > 25,, drop = FALSE]
```

we get

```
structure(c(0, 11, 17, 15, 22, 67, 73, 68, 11, 0, 9, 12, 21, 
67, 73, 67, 17, 9, 0, 6, 19, 70, 74, 68, 15, 12, 6, 0, 13, 64, 
69, 66, 22, 21, 19, 13, 0, 59, 60, 66, 67, 67, 70, 64, 59, 0, 
10, 18, 73, 73, 74, 69, 60, 10, 0, 15, 68, 67, 68, 66, 66, 18, 
15, 0, 31, 35, 36, 34, 38, 77, 76, 59, 31, 30, 36, 37, 39, 75, 
74, 65, 28, 34, 36, 39, 39, 78, 80, 73, 33, 67, 64, 77, 40, 93, 
103, 90, 34, 60, 66, 65, 43, 93, 101, 87, 32, 36, 39, 45, 43, 
85, 95, 82), .Dim = c(8L, 14L))
```

then from

```
a<-colSums(c<25)
b<-which.max(a)
d<-c[c[,b]>25,,drop=FALSE]
```

we get

```
structure(c(67, 73, 68, 67, 73, 67, 70, 74, 68, 64, 69, 66, 59, 
60, 66, 0, 10, 18, 10, 0, 15, 18, 15, 0, 77, 76, 59, 75, 74, 
65, 78, 80, 73, 93, 103, 90, 93, 101, 87, 85, 95, 82), .Dim = c(3L, 
14L))
```

applying once more

```
a<-colSums(d<25)
b<-which.max(a)
e<-d[d[,b]>25,,drop=FALSE]
```

results in a array with no values

structure(numeric(0), .Dim = c(0L, 14L))

Then, the operation can be performed a number of times, and I need to know how many times; in this case it was 3 times.
Also, I need to reduce the number of the lines of the code probably with a loop function, as the action is repetitive.

Comment: What is `tdc`??

Comment: sorry, it is ar instead of tdc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion as shown below:

```
fun<- function(x, i=1){
    a<-which.max(colSums(x<25)) 
    b<-x[x[,a] > 25,, drop = FALSE]
    if(length(b)) Recall(b, i+1) else i
}

fun(ar)
[1] 3
```